# Why do I have MBR and GPT as partition tables?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, mbr

I started with Windows and installed Ubuntu as a dual boot. Thus I thought my partition table should be MBR, since this is what Windows uses.
When i run `gdisk` under Ubuntu, this is the output:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: /dev/sda 
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
```

Why does it say GPT? I boot with Legacy BIOS, not UEFI, thus I thought my Computer must use MBR? What do I miss out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says "GPT" because there is a GPT.

While your protective MBR doesn't contain the true partition table, it apparently contains a bootloader code. BIOS doesn't need to know the partitions to boot – it just executes the code at specific (fixed) address inside MBR. Then it's the bootloader job to utilize GPT data.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Hybrid_MBR_.28LBA_0_.2B_GPT.29):

> In operating systems that support GPT-based boot through BIOS services rather than EFI, the first sector is also still used to store the first stage of the bootloader code, but modified to recognize GPT partitions.